# Python - adding text to a file with a specific format

Tags: python, for-loop, text-files

I guys
the textfiles have a certain structure, and I would like to insert my text exactly in this structure. For this I have to save a number of character (placeholder) for certain columns and only after this number should I continue writing. Its hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string formatting for this.

```
row = " -  {:<13} {:<10} {:<10} {:-<1} {:-<1} {:-<1}".format(version, date, id_, marker[0], marker[1], marker[2])
file.write(row)
```

See [here](https://pyformat.info) for examples on string formatting with padding.

What i used here:

- Placeholders are encapsulated with `{}`
- The colon `:` separates the paceholder name (not used here) and the formatting
- The `<` says text should be left-aligned
- The number after the `<` says how much space should be used at minimum for each word
- The `-` between the colon and the `<` is the fill character. Usually, this is a space, but your A, B, C - columns have a `-` to indicate nothing, so if you were to insert an empty string, it would print a `-` instead.

Comment: OMG that looks nice. Thanks I'll have a look. If its working Im gonna mark it.